# C# - Only keep values in circle of two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a two dimensional array. Lets visualize it as following:

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1   2   3   4   **5**   6   7   8   9   0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0

Now I want to say keep values in a circle of radius 2 with the bold 5 (above) as the center. So the result should be:

0   0   0   0   **5**   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   **4   5   6**   0   0   0   0
0   0   **3   4   5   6   7**   0   0   0
0   0   0   **4   5   6**   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   **5**   0   0   0   0   0

I dont have my laptop right now so I cant share the code but basically what I am doing is iterate through all the cells(values of array) and calculate the distance between the cell and the center by Pythagoras theorem. If the values is less than or equal to 2 leave it otherwise change it to 0.

Now, my code is running perfectly fine and is not very performance intensive (about 0.1 sec for 100x100 array dont know if this is good or bad for 4.2GHz CPU) but I wanted to know if there is an even better way to do this like some sort of matrix operation or anything else or if this is the only way.

Comment: You can skip the square root part, so instead of 2 you would use 4 (i.e. 2 squared).

Comment: If you know the center's index, why not skip the iteration of all the elements in the array by start at the center and fanning out until an element isn't within the circle's radius?

Comment: And you could work out what the bounding square is for the circle, so there isn't any distance calculation needed for rows and columns outside of that.

Comment: What you want is a Sparse Array.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix?force_isolation=true

Comment: One of the things to note is that you only need to calculate 45 deg of X/Y offsets from the center because of the symmetry of a circle (you can get the rest by playing with +/- signs and interchanging X and Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have a center (`row = 2, column = 4`) and `radius = 2`.

Then we should assign `0` to item `[r, c]` depending on *metric*:

- **L1** (Manhattan) `Math.Abs(row - r) + Math.Abs(column - c) > radius`
- **L2** (Euclidean) `(row - r) * (row - r) + (column - c) * (column - c) > radius * radius`
- **Ln** (Arbitrary *finite* `n`) `Math.Pow(Math.Abs(row - r), n) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(column - c), n) > Math.Pow(radius, n)`
- **L∞** (Infinite) `Math.Abs(row - r) > radius || Math.Abs(column - c) > radius`

Assuming that you use **L2** (Euclidean) metric:

```
private static void ClearExceptCircle(int[,] array, int row, int column, int radius) {
  int rowCount = array.GetLength(0);
  int colCount = array.GetLength(1);

  // micro optimization: compute criterium once 
  int limit = radius * radius;

  // Micro optimization: comparing with 0 is faster than with other numbers
  for (int r = rowCount - 1; r >= 0 ; --r)
    for (int c = colCount - 1; c >= 0; --c)
      if ((row - r) * (row - r) + (column - c) * (column - c) > limit)
        array[r, c] = 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/akNkt2)

Answer (score 2):

There are more efficient ways to draw circles. The overall idea is to process the image row by row, and compute the columns where the circle starts and ends, if the circle covers the row. This should allow you to clear all the rows by doing a single index comparison.

To compute the start and end columns you can use the [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) or [Bresenham's Circle Algorithm](https://www.javatpoint.com/computer-graphics-bresenhams-circle-algorithm).

That said, if your current algorithm is *fast enough* I would not bother. Note that a common micro optimization to avoid a somewhat expensive square root is to compare the squared distance:

```
var distSquared = dist * dist;
...
if((x*x + y*y) < distSquared) {...}
```